# What happens to an error passed to "next" if no middleware handles it?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

In Express I can handle errors by passing them to the `next` function callback. If I had registered an error handling middleware function it will be called with that error.

Where does the error go if there is no middleware to handle it, or if that middleware also passes along the error with `next`?

I'm not seeing the error in 'uncaughtException' or 'unhandledRejection'.

(I'm using Express v4.16.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler).

> Express comes with a built-in error handler, which takes care of any errors that might be encountered in the app. This default error-handling middleware function is added at the end of the middleware function stack.
>
> If you pass an error to next() and you do not handle it in an error handler, it will be handled by the built-in error handler; the error will be written to the client with the stack trace. The stack trace is not included in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that they are swallowed, so that sensitive information potentially contained in the error message does not get logged.  You should write your own middleware to do something useful and sane for your application.  I believe the default behaviour has changed in prior versions so check which version you are on and see what's expected.